# Do something only after asynchronous call is finished

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm trying to create a bounce effect on an image after an synchronous AND an asynchronous call but can't figure out how to do it. The problem I'm having now is that I sometimes get both the bounce effect and afterwards `isExecuted` becomes true because the asynchronous event takes some time.

My code should work like this:

Iterate over each object in `myEnum` and execute the following

- if `myCondition1` is equal too `myCondition2` set `isExecuted = true`
- if above is not true, call an asynchronous method which evaluates some stuff, if it's true it will set `isExecuted = true`.
- wait for all above is finished, then if `isExecuted` still is false, bounce the image.

Here's the code:

```
var isExecuted = false;

myEnum.each() 
{
    if (myCondition1 == myCondition2) { //Synchronous 
        isExecuted = true;
        return false; //stop the iteration
    }   
    else {
        MyAsyncFunction(myCondition2, function(isTrue) { // Asynchronous
            if (isTrue) {
                isExecuted = true;
                return false; //stop the iteration
            }                   
        });
    }
});

// Execute this ONLY when above code is finished executing
if (isExecuted == false) {
    BounceImage();
}
```

Please note that the async function is not always executed but the bounce check must always be executed if `isExecuted` is true.

Comment: Where is the `index` in `$("a#" + index + " img")` coming from? The generic answer to this is: Use promises and `Promise.all`.

Comment: callbacks can help but I don't know about writing them in javascript

Comment: Also, what is `myVar`?

Comment: @FelixKling It's coming from `myEnum.each(function(index)` and it's not really relevant to the question...

Comment: @MadhusoodanP Why comment at all when you wouldn't know how to help?

Comment: @dadde: But the `if` statement is outside the `myEnum.each()` callback.

Comment: @Tomalak it can be anything... if "a" == "a" then true else false...? Let me update the code

Comment: Now the code is even more wrong.... Please post a [mcve]. *"it's not really relevant to the question..."* It's relevant in so far as it seems you want to execute `$("a#" + index + " img").stop().effect("bounce", ...)` after all async requests are done. Or is that not correct? If not, then where is the problem? Put the `if` statement inside the callback, or inside a function that you call from the callback.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @FelixKling How about now (edited the question some more)? If I put the `if` inside the callback it will only bounce when the async event is true but I want the bounce effect also if only the synchronous event is executed (notice the `return false` that breaks the loops).

Comment: The `return false;` inside the asynchronous callback has no effect on the `.each` loop. I think you have to approach this entirely differently.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh yes you are right thanks for pointing that out. But what about the bounce?

Comment: I'd refactor everything so that you can do something like `process(myEnum).then(isExecuted => { if (!isExecuted) { BounceImage(); }});`, where `process` somehow iterates over your array, performs the async  calls and comparisons and returns a promise.

Comment: @FelixKling Good! Can you elaborate with an example? I'm rather new to javascripting...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This whole setup won't work as you want because you cannot stop the iteration from the asynchronous callback. Instead you have to process the array (or whatever `myEnum` is) asynchronously and do something afterwards. I highly recommend to learn about [promises](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/primers/promises).

```js
function process(array, cb) {
  var i = 0;
  
  function p(v) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      try {
        // call the callback, passing in the current value and 
        // a callback to control execution
        cb(v, function next(stop, result) {
          if (stop) {
            // if stop = true, abort the iteration and resolve the passed in value
            resolve(result);
          } else if (i < array.length) {
            // else if there are more elements left, process them
            resolve(p(array[i++]));
          } else {    // else resolve to the passed in value
            resolve(result);
          }
        });
      } catch(e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    });
  }
  
  // start with the first element
  return p(array[0]);
}

process([1,2,3], function(v, next) {
  if (v == 2) {
    return next(true, v);
  }
  next();
}).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Applied to your code it would look something like

```
process(myEnum, function(v, next) {
  if (myCondition1 == myCondition2) {
    return next(true, true);
  } else {
    MyAsyncFunction(myCondition2, function(isTrue) {
      if (isTrue) {
        return next(true, true);
      }
      next();                 
    });
  }
}).then(function(isExecuted) {
  if (!isExecuted) {
    BounceImage();
  }
});
```

---

Of course you can also use an existing library that allows you to do this. There a many different (potentially more elegant) ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead, use callbacks:

```
function asyncFunction (a, b, c, callback) {
  ...
  callback();
}

asyncFunction(1, 2, 3, function () {
  doSomethingOnceDone();
});
```

This is a very common practice. It's how most async Chrome APIS do it, just to name one thing.